# Creating a list of buttons

Tags: .net, wpf

I have this xaml code

```
<StackPanel Margin="0 50 0 0">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource WordButton}" Content="Гитара" 
                        x:Name="FirstWordButton" Click="FirstWordButton_Click"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource WordButton}" Content="Дерево"
                        x:Name="SecondWordButton" Click="SecondWordButton_Click"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource WordButton}" Content="Дверь"
                        x:Name="ThirdWordButton" Click="ThirdWordButton_Click"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource WordButton}" Content="Лес"
                        x:Name="FourthWordButton" Click="FourthWordButton_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

I`m not very happy about the fact that for handle, for instance all buttons, I need to write their names. Is it possible to create a list or resource and put all there all these buttons to handle buttons like this?

```
foreach (Button B in "resource")
     ................
```

Sorry for bad English!

Comment: See [Data templating overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#defining-a-simple-datatemplate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Button` elements are added to the `Children` collection of the `StackPanel` when the XAML markup is processed so you could just give the `StackPanel` a name in the XAML markup:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="sp" ... />
```

...and then access the `Button` elements like this in the code:

```
foreach (Button button in sp.Children.OfType<Button>())
```